# 3 columns responsive layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to do 3 columns responsive layout. It should work for `IE8` also. So I am using `float: left` for elements in row, but I faced with some troubles:

1. The last images in row has unexpected height. I understand that it occurs because `.news_preview { width: 100%; }`, but I do not understand how to fix it.
2. `.news__item` elements should have the same `height = 100%`. I know how to fix it using JavaScript, but is it possible to fix it using css only for my `.news__item` elements with `float: left;`?

The example:  https://jsfiddle.net/3nxetb45/1/

Comment: You should use clear:both carefully and by this your last div's height issue will be solve.

Comment: you want like this https://jsfiddle.net/3nxetb45/3/

Comment: Thanks! The first issue is fixed :)

Comment: What is others..let me know.

Comment: .news__item elements have not the same height. point 2 in my question.

Comment: @llya z like this https://jsfiddle.net/3nxetb45/5/

Comment: @Leothelion yes, it works, but is it good approach to use `tables` in adaptive layout?

Comment: Well no comments on this. If you are ok with my answer then i can post as answer. Depends on you.

Comment: @Leothelion yes, I am ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are few points which you should be aware. I have removed `height:100%` from .main and used `clear:both` after div.

About using clear:both, use them just after floated element so by this there will be no extra height or space issue.

About second issue, i have used `display:table` to main element and `display:table-cell` to child and removed `float:left` to get the desired output. Also we have replaced bottom-border to get result. For more detail check fiddle..

Check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3nxetb45/5/)